# have ghci list all possible type class instances?

Tags: haskell, typeclass, ghci

When ghc can't determine a concrete type class instance, you'll get a message like:

```
No instance for ...
  arising from a use of `it'
The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
Note: there are several potential instances:
  (lists a few instances)
  ...plus 13 others
Possible fix: ...
```

Is there way to display all of the defined instances of a type class?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `:info` command (shortened to `:i`) to do this:

```
> :i Num
class Num a where
  (+) :: a -> a -> a
  (*) :: a -> a -> a
  (-) :: a -> a -> a
  negate :: a -> a
  abs :: a -> a
  signum :: a -> a
  fromInteger :: Integer -> a
    -- Defined in ‘GHC.Num’
instance Num Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Num’
instance Num Int -- Defined in ‘GHC.Num’
instance Num Float -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
instance Num Double -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
```